# Which threading model can I choose?

Tags: multithreading, redis, pthreads, memcached, threadpool

I am writing a system something similar to a key-value store, but differently, the get and set operation is frequently called.

In server end, I use the 'one thread per client' threading model just now. But in this application, the connections from client end of every task is about ten thousands, so the model I use is slow.

Which threading model can I choose in the situation?

Thanks

Comment: which programming language are you working on ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the "one thread per client" model is very efficient. In term of raw performance, latency, number of system calls, it is difficult to do better. However, it is not very scalable, because:

- each thread has its own stack, so the memory/connection ratio is bad
- the OS scheduling overhead increases with the number of threads
- concurrency management primitives (mutex, condition variables, etc ...) are less efficient when a lot of threads are blocked on the same resource.

I think the critical point to choose a good threading model is to evaluate the relative costs of your operations, and whether they can be blocking or not. For instance, is the cost of protocol marshalling/unmarshalling higher than the access to the internal data structures? Can data acccess generate a blocking disk I/O? etc ...

Depending on the result, you can imagine various models.

A first possible model (memcached model):

- 1 thread (event loop) for signal management, and TCP accept management.
  Each time a new connection is accepted, it is dispatched (through a round robin) to one of the connection management threads
- n threads for connection management.
  Each thread is an even loop (e)polling on its associated connections. Any incoming query is processed by the thread. Any access to the global data structures has to be protected by some mutual exclusion mechanism.

This model works fine if the data structure accesses are fast and predictable operations. If mutual exclusion is too complex, or if there is too many contention on the global data structures, this model can be improved by adding a dedicated thread to manage data structure operations.

- 1 thread (event loop) for signal management, and TCP accept management.
- n threads (event loop) for connection management
- fast in-memory queues
- 1 thread to handle all data structure accesses, listening to the fast in-memory queue

In this model, the connection threads decode/encode the protocol (expensive operation) and delegate all data access to the dedicated thread by posting events to the in-memory queue. A specific file descriptor is used to wake up the event loop once the dedicated thread posts a result for the connection thread. All data access operations are serialized, no mutex is required to protect the associated data structure.

The previous models assume that data access is cheap or cheaper than protocol management itself. If this is wrong, then the following model is probably better:

- 1 thread (event loop) for signal management, and TCP accept management.
- n threads (event loop) for connection management
- fast in-memory queues
- m threads for data/query management, listening to memory queues

In this model, the n connection threads just handle the protocol encode/decode operations and delegate everything else to a pool of m threads. These threads have to manage the concurrent accesses to gobal data structures. Eventually, they can block on I/Os or heavy calculations provided you have enough of them.

There are many other possible variations, these are just the main ideas.

Comment: The only elaboration on Didier's excellent answer is that you can make the event loop threads self scaling. If an event loop thread using epoll() analyses the average time it is blocked in epoll() it can decide how busy it is. If epoll() is always returning immediately then the thread isn't keeping up with demand. All you need is a way for that thread to be able to pass some of its connections back to a management thread. This in turn then starts up another thread to handle these connections. Sounds like a lot of coding, but you'll end up with a self tuning server application.

Answer (score 2):

You probably should include additional details as to why you are seeing the system being so slow. If you are using mutexes, how did you design them? Does the mutex protect the entire key-value storage or a subset of it. Typically, splitting the big table into individual small tables (rows) helps things become more parallel. Also, are you running into issues of a thread waiting for another. If so, you probably would be better off using conditional variables.